# How to find objects in memory

Tags: java

Is there any way to find that a specific object is still in the memory or not? For example I have a `JFrame` called `GuiSearch`. When I called some method it will be disposed. I want to find is it still in the memory or disposed. I am new to java. Please help me.

Edit: What I want to do is find that the specific object is still in the memory or not and if it is in the memory, I want to call a method and if it is not, call another method.

Comment: Why would you ever need that? Keep a reference around and be done. Plus, consider that it has horrible time complexity.

Comment: No my primary target is to find that the specific object is still in the memory or not and if it is in memory I want to call one method if it is not call another method. That's what I want to do.

Comment: That's a horrible idea. (1) Objects may stay in memory well after they become unreachable. Depending on that means depending on the whim of the (specific version and kind of) garbage collector your code runs under. (2) It's entirely possible to do without this, fix your design instead of introducing an unclean, dog slow hack.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `disposed` cleans up resources hidden by the object.

As long as you have a reference to it, the object is still in memory.  Depending on what disposed does, you could have an object which is "disposed" and still in be memory as you still have a reference to it.

Comment: And even if there is no reference to an object, it may very well stay in memory for quite a while.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to do this for debugging and not via the code. If that's the case, what you want to is dump the heap memory and check it via tools such as [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad programming practice and you never do it. To see objects in memory you can use jvisualvm - which comes Sun JDK it self. This provides a visual interface for viewing detailed information about Java application while they are running on a Java Virtual Machine.